# cannot resolve reference to methods

Tags: kotlin

I've got interfaces

```
interface IIMSIdentifiable {
    fun setImsId(id : String)
    fun getImsId() : String
}

interface IIMSConsumer : IIMSIdentifiable {
    fun consumeAsync(message : GRLMessage)
}
```

And I've got a class that contains object with `IIMSConsumer` type

```
class IMSObject<IIMSConsumer> : Thread {
    constructor(component : IIMSConsumer) {
        obj = component
        // IMSContext.instance.registerObject(this) // hm type mismatch
    }

    val objectMessageQueue = LinkedBlockingDeque<GRLMessage>()
    val obj : IIMSConsumer
    var isRunning = true

    override fun run() {
        while(isRunning) {
            processMessages()
        }
    }

    fun stopProcessing() {
        isRunning = false
    }

    fun processMessages() {
        objectMessageQueue.forEach {
            obj.consumeAsync(it)
        }
    }

    fun getObjectId() : String {
        return obj.getImsId()
    }
}
```

But it cannot resolve references

```
fun processMessages() {
    objectMessageQueue.forEach {
        obj.consumeAsync(it) // cannot resolve reference !!!
    }
}

fun getObjectId() : String {
    return obj.getImsId() // cannot resolve reference !!!
}
```

What is the problem? Oddly enought it did not ask for imports despite being located in different packages

```
com.lapots.game.journey.ims.domain.IMSObject
com.lapots.game.journey.ims.api.IIMSConsumer
```

I tried to test in on something simpler and get the same error with `unresolved reference`

```
interface IConsumer {
    fun consume() : String
}

class Generic<IConsumer>(val consumer : IConsumer) {
    fun invoke() {
        print(consumer.consume()) // unresolved reference
    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val consumer = object : IConsumer {
        override fun consume() : String {
            return "I consume"
        }
    }
    val generic = Generic<IConsumer>(consumer)
    generic.invoke()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class Generic<IConsumer>(val consumer : IConsumer) {`

You are creating a class `Generic` with a generic type parameter called `IConsumer`. This type parameter will shadow the interface you defined within that class, so you it actually says is:

`class Generic<IConsumer : Any>(val consumer : Any) {`

That is why it cannot resolve the method, since the generic parameter can only be interpreted as `Any`.

To fix either change the type parameter to have the appropriate names and bound (`class Generic<T : IConsumer>(val consumer : T) {`) or remove the generics entirely